# splinter click button with no attributes

Tags: python, splinter

I'm using splinter to try and click a button that has no attributes. The html code in developer tools is

```
<div class="numeric">
     <button>0</button>
     <button>1</button>
     <button>...</button>
     <button>9</button>
</div>
```

that executes a jquery.

My code looks like this

```
browser.find_by_css("numeric").find_by_text("0").first.click()
```

However I am getting that numeric is not found. I have also tried #numeric as well.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really the css for the div class.
You could try to find it by xpath using this:

```
browser.find_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'numeric')]")
```